# How to allow only internal (cron) requests in my App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

Currently I'm using a nodejs App Engine (flexible environment), to do scheduled tasks, like shutting down and starting instances or creating shapshots. The problem is that these App Engines are accessible from everywhere, but I only want them to be accessible within my Google Cloud Network. 
I can't really seem to get the firewall to work that way. 
Does anyone know whether there is a way or not to do that?

Comment: would it be sufficient for you to secure the Cron Jobs?

Answer (score 7):

To enforce cron jobs to be triggered just within Google Cloud Network you can check the `X-Appengine-Cron: true` header of a request and client IP is `0.1.0.1`.

From [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#validating_cron_requests):

> You might want to validate that requests to your cron URLs are coming
>   from App Engine and not from another source. You can do so by
>   validating an HTTP header and the source IP address for the request:
>
> - Requests from the Cron Service will also contain a HTTP header:
>
>   `X-Appengine-Cron: true`
>
> The X-Appengine-Cron header is set internally by Google App Engine.
>   If your request handler finds this header it can trust that the
>   request is a cron request. The X- headers are stripped by App Engine
>   when they originate from external sources so that you can trust this
>   header.
>
> - Google App Engine issues cron requests from the IP address 0.1.0.1

Comment: tried this in Postman, definitely strips out `X-Appengine-Cron`, but not all `X-` headers. I imagine any `X-` headers appengine itself uses, it'll strip. I was able to send `X-AppengineCrn` just fine (to sanity-check postman was working)

Comment: That’s the point so only AppEngine can set the header so you can trust it.